# npm update does nothing

Tags: reactjs, npm, drag-and-drop

I am trying to update a specific npm package - "[react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd)" although I don't think there is a problem with it. When I run "npm -v react-beautiful-dnd" in my project's directory, I can see that it's "6.4.1". I inherited the project, so the version is probably the latest stable one at the time. I wanted to update it to the newest one - 10.0.0, so the first thing I did was changing the version in package.json to the desired and then running npm install (without --save, wisely or not).

Everything went through fine, but I when I run "npm -v ..." it still shows the same version. From what I know, the stable version of the package is much higher than 6.4.1, so I don't have a clue what's up with that. When I run npm list -g and try to find the package through cmd + f, I don't even have it on the list, so it's likely not a problem with that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Updating local packages

Navigate to the root directory of your project and ensure it contains a package.json file:

`cd /path/to/project`

In your project root directory, run the [update][npm-update] command:

`npm update`

To test the update, run the [outdated][npm-outdated] command. There should not be any output.

`npm outdated`

you can also check out npm package update [Document.](https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry)

Comment: Thanks! There is not, but when I run "npm -v react-beautiful-dnd" it still shows the same thing.

Comment: I am a moron. Thanks for your answers!